# A question regarding Parseval's identity.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

In most books/websites, Proposition 2 (see below) is either stated for a Hilbert space or proved via Riesz-Fischer. Does the follow approach (which seems to work in an inner product space) fall down somewhere?

I would be very grateful for any comments.

---

Let $X$ be a complex inner product space.

Suppose $S=(e_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ is an orthonormal sequence in $X.$

*Proposition 1.* $S$ is a total sequence (i.e. the linear span of $S$ is dense in $X$) if and only if
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(x,e_k)e_k \; \; \; \; \forall x \in X.$$

*Proof.* (if) Clear.

(only if) Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. There exist $c_1,\ldots,c_N \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$\left\|\,x-\sum_{i=1}^Nc_ie_i\,\right\|<\varepsilon.$$
However, by the "minimum property of Fourier coefficients" we have
$$\left\|\,x-\sum_{i=1}^N(x,e_i)e_i\,\right\|\leq\left\|\,x-\sum_{i=1}^Nc_ie_i\,\right\|$$
and so we are done. Q.E.D.

*Proposition 2.* $S$ is total sequence if and only if
$$\|x\|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|(x,e_k)|^2 \; \; \; \; \forall x \in X.$$

*Proof.* Observe that, for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\left\|\,x-\sum_{i=1}^N(x,e_i)e_i\,\right\|^2=\|x\|^2-\sum_{i=1}^N|(x,e_i)|^2.$$
The result now follows by combining this observation with Proposition 1. Q.E.D.

Comment: Your aguments look sound. More generally: If $S$ is an orthonormal subset of an inner product space $X$, and if $M$ is linear span of elements of $S$, then the closure $M^{c}$ includes $x$ iff Parseval's equality holds for $x$ with respect to $S$. The proof works because you have something for $\sum_{s \in S}(x,s)s$ to converge to. (If $\sum_{s\in S}|(x,s)|^{2} < \|x\|^{2}$, then you can't necessarily form $\sum_{s\in S}(x,s)s$ if $X$ is not complete.)